# working of IEnumerable in for looping controls

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

Can anyone help me how exactly this code works.
how IEnumarable gets saved in memory 
what exactly var does in this context? why they used concat in this code what exactly is it concatenating

```
public IEnumerable<Control> GetAll(Control control,Type type)
{
    var controls = control.Controls.Cast<Control>();
    return controls.SelectMany(ctrl => GetAll(ctrl,type)).Concat(controls) 
                                                         .Where(c => c.GetType() == type);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `IEnumerable` is an interface. When a type implements `IEnumerable` exposes an enumerator, that can be used for an iteration through the types elements.

For instance an array implements this interface. Hence you can loop through it's items using a `foreach`  statement:

```
foreach(var item in array)
{
    // ...
}
```

This method, `GetAll` returns a sequence of `Control` objects. This could be an array of `Control` objects, a list of `Control` objects or every type that implements the `IEnumerable<Control>`. This method gets as parameters two objects, one of `Control` type and the other of `Type` type. Then in the variable called `controls` you store the collection of controls contained within the control. For further information on this, please have a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controls(v=vs.110).aspx). After this, here:

```
return controls.SelectMany(ctrl => GetAll(ctrl,type))
               .Concat(controls)
               .Where(c => c.GetType() == type);
```

foreach control in the controls you get it's contained controls of the same time recursively. And then you join the two sequences with the `controls` and you return them.

In a few words, if you pass there a control whose type is a button then the method `GetAll` will return you a sequence of all the buttons that are contained within the same panel.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use:

```
 control.Controls.OfType<type>();
```

If you want the *immediate* child controls of the **control** whose type are **type**

Comment: That only returns the first level deep, while his code retrieves all controls.